# How can we add multiple images with other details to the database table in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have **news table** with following fields

**news**

id , title, description and video

and **news_images** table for storing multiple images

**news_images**

id, image and news_id

i need to enter all information in create news page and save them into **news** and **news_image** table

also how will these all populate in view file

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        'description:ntext',
        'video',
        [
'attribute'=>'image',
'value'=>Yii::getAlias('@siteUrl').'/'.$model->image,
'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],

    ],
]) ?>
```

Instead of single image .i need to show all images

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images from has_many relation of `News` model:

```
for ($model->images as $image) {
    echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@siteUrl').'/'.$model->image, ['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']);
}
```

**Where** `$model->images` **is** :

```
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewsImages::className(), ['news_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: any idea about adding the multiple images to news_image table and rest of data to news table ??

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md#uploading-multiple-files-